# Issues setting up Single-Sign On with Office 365

Tags: active-directory, activesync, microsoft-office-365

I am doing Prepare for single sign-on.

Following this tutorial http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh125004.aspx.

When I run Microsoft Office 365 for enterprises Deployment Readiness Tool I get two issues.

1. Discovered groups without a displayname 
   Note: Groups 
   without a displayname will NOT get synchronized to Office 365. 
   Updating the 
   displayname attribute in Active Directory for each group will resolve this issue 
   when DirSync is enabled. 
   Review the file groupsdisplay.csv in the folder 
   c:\office365reskit\do_not_modify\ for more information
2. It appears that your schema is not prepared for an Exchange Hybrid Deployment 
   (Exchange Server 2010 SP2 or above) 
   You may ignore this message if you do 
   not plan on migrating from Exchange on-premises 
   Or if you will leverage 
   other tools to migrate such as the simple/staged migration tools

How can I resolve it?

(

For other DGs you would like to synchronize, please have a look at the following action plan:

1. On your local Active Directory domain controller, click Start, point to All Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Active Directory Users and Computers.
2. Select the root of the tool, and then click Advanced Features on the View menu.
3. Locate the user security group that you want to adjust, right-click the group, and then click Properties.
4. On the Attribute Editor tab, locate and then select the displayName attribute, and then click Edit. In the Value box, type the display name that you want, and then click OK two times.
5. Wait for the next sync of force a sync.(i did that but how to do force a sync)

)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have answered your own questions.

1) No displayName on groups, so add a displayName to all groups missing them.
I suppose an LDAP query like `(&(objectClass=group)(!(displayName=*)))` should find them for you.

Either fix them via LDAP (since you now have a list of DN's) or by hand.

2) If you do not have Exchange in your AD right now, you do not need the correct schema.  Do you have Exchange in your AD?  You do not mention it.  If you do not, nothing to see here, I would imagine.